# iPhone - Horizontal scrolling appears only on home page

Tags: iphone, css, html, frontend

I cannot for the life of me figure this one out.

I am developing a pretty straight-forward website and on the home page (the home page only) when viewed on an iPhone, there's a weird horizontal scroll.

On other pages, this does not occur.

I have gone through with firebug to see if anything is stupidly wider than anywhere else...but it's not. Even removing entire parts like the header and footer etc make no difference. Only after removing *everything* on the home page does the iPhone not horizontally scroll.

**Website in question:**
http://bit.ly/YctLKP

It seems as though the home page is slightly more 'zoomed-in' than any other page. Could it be something going on there? And if so, why is this occurring?

I have checked on desktop browsers for any indication that there's a difference in the widths...and I cannot see anything wrong at all. Only on iPhone and on the home page does it seem to do this.

I would appreciate some help.

I know that the website is not 'mobile friendly' as such...but I would expect this particular problem not to occur.

Many thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many hours...I still couldn't figure this out.

**In the end I have had to use:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1030" />
```

1030 pixels is the widest this particular design will / should go.

This seems to have at least removed the horizontal scrolling. As to why this was happening anyway and only on one particular page...I have no idea.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've got fixed width elements eg. with 990px width declarations.

At first, try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` inside your head section.

Comment: I don't understand how that would affect it, as it's not affecting other pages. This issue only occurs on the home, even though they're using the same DIV ID and Class names as the other pages. Also, adding that meta tag only makes it worse, because the view is then stretched out further and horizontal scrolling increases.

Answer (score 0):

Your header has fixed with of 990px in CSS.

Also as previous comments suggest, you have to correct viewport to match device width.

Safari offers good responsive design tools that you can use. On mac os x, open responsive design view from Develop-menu or press alt-command-R. Then you can view your web page from perspective of mobile browser and by right-cliking you can inspect problematic parts of the web page.